# Cannot get id of subscription in request

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

I'm trying to get the id of the selected subscription and pass it to the controller, but for some reason when I dd() or print_r() the id in the controller, it returns the same id regardless of which subscription I click.

Regardless if i click the first '+' button or the second one it always returns the same id when I print_r() it.

[image]

```
Array ( [_token] => iFimNDCv0q4rq7OmmUWGN8SGr2Bq0brsiRMLIzBD [subscription] => 2 )
```

Even when I click the first one, which should have '1' as the id, it still returns '2'.

This is my route for it in web.php

```
Route::post('/transaction/store', 'TransactionController@store')->name('transaction.store');
```

This is the function in the controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // continue here
    print_r($request->input());
}
```

And this is the form tag that's responsible for send the id (which is inside a foreach statement in blade)

```
<form id="batch" action="{{route('transaction.store')}}" method="POST">
     @csrf
     <input type="hidden" name="subscription" value="{{$subscription->id}}" form="batch">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark" form="batch">+</button>
</form>
```

Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: you are creating multiple forms all with a hidden input with the same name that reference the same form?

Comment: For multiple name attribute, make it dynamic `name="subscription[]"` now check from controller `dd($request->subscription);`

Comment: @lagbox there is another form outside of this one that's why i used a 'form' attribute, and yes there are also hidden inputs inside there

Comment: its not one form, its many because of the loop ... all those hidden inputs reference the same form name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to make the form id dynamic!

```
<form id="batch-{{$subscription->id}}" action="{{route('transaction.store')}}" method="POST">
     @csrf
     <input type="hidden" name="subscription" value="{{$subscription->id}}" form="batch-{{$subscription->id}}">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark" form="batch-{{$subscription->id}}">+</button>
 </form>
```